# What does the data-url attribute do in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

Trying to figure out the basic structure of a page and came across a blog that had the `data-url` attribute. What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That attribute serves to identify pages that are auto-generated by jQM. From the **[jQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html)**:

> ...Pages that are auto-generated by
>   plugins use the following special
>   data-url structure: <div
>   data-url="page.html&subpageidentifier">
>
> So, for example, a page generated by
>   the listview plugin may have an
>   data-url attribute like this:
>   data-url="artists.html&ui-page=listview-1"
>
> When a page is requested, jQuery
>   Mobile knows to split the URL at
>   "&ui-page" and make an HTTP request to
>   the portion of the URL before that
>   key. In the case of the listview
>   example mentioned above, the URL would
>   look like this:
>   http://example.com/artists.html&ui-page=listview-1
>   ...and jQuery Mobile would request
>   artists.html, which would then
>   generate its sub-pages, creating the
>   div with
>   data-url="artists.html&ui-page=listview-1",
>   which it will then display as the
>   active page.
>
> Note that the data-url attribute of
>   the element contains the full URL
>   path, not just the portion after
>   &ui-page=. This allows jQuery Mobile
>   to use a single consistent mechanism
>   that matches URLs to page data-url
>   attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The data-url attribute also serves to update the hash when using redirects or linking to directories. Check out the [Redirects and linking to directories](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html) section.