# HTML input function

Tags: html, input

I want to know what `data-url` does in a `input` function? example there is this thing in the code I am working on - `<input id="something" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/index.php">`

Can someone please tell me what `data-url` does

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917111/what-does-the-data-url-attribute-do-in-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. `data-*` is a custom data attribute you can use to store whatever you like. https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/10/using-data-attributes-in-javascript-and-css/. Essentially it's a simple way to store data to be used by scripts.

As the [W3 states](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes):

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to
>   the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate
>   attributes or elements.

See also: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/